# Compatibility of JDBC driver with Oracle 19c Database

Tags: database, oracle, upgrade, compatibility

We are currently using ojdc14(Java 1.6) with Oracle 11g Database and want to upgrade the DB to 19c version.
I wanted to know which ojdbc jars are compatible with Oracle 19c database?

Comment: Oracle has a [JDBC FAQ](https://www.oracle.com/uk/database/technologies/faq-jdbc.html) which should help you.

Comment: It depends on the JDK version that you are using. You can always use the latest 19c version on JDBC download page (https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-downloads.html). Also, ojdbc8.jar is used with JDK8 and JDK11 and ojdbc11.jar can be used if you are using JDK17.